# Error in as.numeric(bbox) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r

What this error means??? Maybe an error with coordinate format? Or in the polygon's format/shape?
The script is from Zizka's tutorial "Downloading occurrences from GBIF", in short I need to download occurrences from a specific group of plants that occurs inside this polygon (a multipolygon actually). The polygon is a shapefile that I created in ArcMAP. 
This is the script I used to download occurrences from GBIF:

```
library(countrycode)
library(ConR)
library(devtools)
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)
library(maps)
library(rgbif)
library(raster)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sp)
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(arulesViz)
library(arules)

tax_key <- name_suggest(q = "Apocynaceae", rank = "Family") 

lapply(tax_key$key, "occ_count")
tax_key <- tax_key$key[1]
occ_count(tax_key, country = "BR")

mataatlant <- readOGR('C:/Users/brena/Mata Atlântica/MA GRID', layer = 'MAGrid30')
rgeos::writeWKT(mataatlant)

study_a <- mataatlant

dat_ne <- occ_search(taxonKey = tax_key, return = "data", hasCoordinate = T, 
                     geometry = mataatlant, limit = 50000) 
*Error in as.numeric(bbox) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'*
```

Comment: S4's are a method of object oriented programming in R. Is bbox some object you are creating?(I am assumeing not) It would be beneficial to narrow down the location of the error so maybe execute the code line by line. It would seem that it is some internal code within a package you are using that is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

A simplification, but:

You have a a data type mismatch. The s4 object is a shapefile (or an R analogue, such as spatial points/polyongs data frame, or a simple_feature. A double is a field in the data table in ArcMap. You've told R to calculate the shapefile, not the field in the shapefile.

Comment: So should I put the shapefiles's dimension? This is a multipolygon, its a problem?

Comment: Can't tell from the code you've presented. I'll hazard a guess that the you need to input a 'double' (a long number) and you are somehow trying to use a shapefile instead of the number (or numbers).